# Laravel : Hasmany relationship returning empty results

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

i have 3 tables

1. shops
2. packages
3. shop_packages

as below

**Shops**

[image]

**Packages**

[image]

**Shop Packages**
[image]

i am using following relationship in **Shop Model**

```
 public  function  packages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class,'shop_packages','shop_id','package_id');
 }
```

and below in  **Package Model**

```
 public  function  shop(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class,'shop_packages','package_id','shop_id');
 }
```

when i try to get

```
 Package::with('shop')->get();
```

it returns me packages but shops remain empty can someone please guide me how can i fix this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: >belongsToMany(Package::class 
check this

Comment: @Shibon i did not get your point please could you elaborate ?

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong : a Package belongs to many Shop, and a Shop has many Package. Isn't it ?

Comment: yes  ,,  @Ludo.C  i am not sure how it  should bel can you please guide

Comment: Please post Shop Packages table schema

Comment: @SahandMoghadam its there in the original post , please check

Answer (score 0):

It is applicable for Laravel 9, If your Laravel version is lower than check the `many-to-many-polymorphic-relations` for documenton appropriate your version.

In Package Model

```
/**
     * Get all of the shops for the package.
     */
    public function shops()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class, 'shop_packages');
    }
```

In Shop Model

```
/**
     * Get all of the packages for the package.
     */
    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class, 'shop_packages');
    }
```

Comment: i am using laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

Your DB capture does not correspond to your relationships.

In Package model you should have something like :

```
public function packages(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class,'shop_packages');
}
```

Otherwise in Shop model you should have :

```
public function shops(){
   return $this->hasMany(Package::class);
}
```

You have to use the appropriate relationship regarding to your needs.